# DatePicker calendar tacking too much place in layout

Tags: android, android-layout, calendar, datepicker, adt

I'm new in Android dev, and I'm trying to do a little app for myself. In one activity, I want to select a date. Obviously I am using a datePicker, the thing is I have an issue, either using the calendar or the spinner view.
I am setting a minDate (current date) and a max date (7 days after that). I don't like the spinner because for example, it keeps offering July and September when launched today (I you have a solution for that, I'll take it). And if I use the calendar view, I get this:
[image]
My issue is the big white space you're seeing, there is another item below that, but it is shown fat too much at the bottom. The size currently occupied by the calendar is the size of the full calendar. Any way to get around this?

Thanks!

EDIT:
I obviously forgot some details.
Here is the current XML:

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker"
    android:calendarViewShown="true"
    android:spinnersShown="false"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

And the Java:

```
date = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
long currentDate = cal.getTimeInMillis()
date.setMinDate(currentDate);
date.setMaxDate(currentDate + 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000);
date.getCalendarView().setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

for your DatePicker in the layout xml.
Something like below:

```
<DatePicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

try something like below, it will reduce the size by half, if you want to reduce more, adjust the values of scaleX,scaleY:

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker"
    android:calendarViewShown="true"
    android:spinnersShown="false"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:scaleX=".5"
    android:scaleY=".5"/>
```

To use pixel values in height and weight:

```
<DatePicker
    android:layout_width="12dip"
    android:layout_height="12dip"
/>
```

Comment: You're right, some details are missing. Thanks for your help, but that's not the issue here. I will update my question. Thx!

Comment: Thanks, but it only scales the content, not the box itself :/

Comment: Have you tried giving pixel values for height and weight

Comment: I'ld like to avoid that :/